# ExpressJS/PassportJS: Authentication vs. Sessions

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

I am starting out with NodeJS (and web programming) and having trouble getting the authentication and sessions understood. I read many tutorials and just when I think I had it, I get confused. My problem is dealing with both authentication (Signup/Login) and persistent sessions.

I am using PassportJS, and after many tutorials later, I think I finally found a great one here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

But now I'm confused how sessions are handled by serializeUser and deserializeUser. Please bear with me for this novice question, but my understanding is a that a user ID is used to track the sessions.

So my questions are:

1. The user ID, is autogenerated by Passport?
2. Serialization simply adds the user ID to the session cookie?
3. Finally, how can I change the session parameters like maxAge? Where should I set them? I'm a little confused with Express sessions and the Passport sessions.

If anybody can provide a link to a good tutorial that is appreciated too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passport does not directly manage your session, it simply uses your session.  So you will configure the life of your session based on the middleware you use.  With express's own cookie middleware, for example:

```
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
```

As far as Passport, it does not generate anything.  It invokes your authentication, serialize, and deserialize functions to find, load, and reload the user data.  The flow is like this:

```
 passport.use(<new Strategy>(function(username,password,done) { }))
```

This accepts a login form submission with a username and password value that gets passed into your implementation.  Typically a DB lookup that produces a user object (based on your model/implementation) passed into the `done(err,user)` function.

Now that you've found a User object it will be set onto the request object, but that is only good for that request.  The session is used to serialize the user (typically the ID of the user object) so that it can be passed in again to reconstitute a user.

```
 my.serializeUser = function(user,done)
```

This is your function to which Passport passes the User object you found.  This is where you construct a String representation of that User and pass it to `done(err,string)`  Whatever you pass as the second argument gets stored with the session.

```
 my.deserializeUser = function(string,request,done)
```

This is your function where the key (created by your serializeUser) gets passed back to you.  Your code then uses it to retrieve the full User object (possibly a DB query by that user's ID) and pass back a full user object to `done(err,user)` This again gets set on the request for your handlers.

So it's all up to you how to serialize, deserialize, and authenticate.  Passport provides the hooks so that you can set auth requirements on routes the same way despite the strategy you pick.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt. That made few things clear. The question I have now is, in deserializeUser, findById() is not given an implementation. Is this provided by Passport? Also, if I understand correct, when a user is logged in, Passport/Express will create a User object and store the credentials (username, password) in to that object. And the ID of this object (which can change across sessions) is stored in the session cookie. When logout() is called, this User object is deleted. Am I close?

Comment: Most of the examples I've seen on Passport make the assumption you are using MongoDB (findOne, findById, etc)  It's just to imply a database lookup and the return of a JSON/JS Object.  The ID may change if you want it to, the main point is that you are able to retrieve the necessary data (permissions, email, etc) without having to store all of it in the session.  Remember that YOUR code is what creates the User object in whatever form necessary.  Passport helps you manage the object through the route handlers and auth chain.  Logout would remove it from the session, but not delete anything.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I think I got a the hang of it a bit. I will go through the code again. I didn't know findById is a Mongo API. That was very helpful. Cheers.

Comment: No problem.  For many, Mongo and Node are fairly quick to get running with because you can almost pass the data around without any transformation needed since it's all in JS and JSON.  Mongoose is a typical package/middleware for managing it via Node if you want to follow the patterns you find in the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html

Comment: Thank you Matt. I'm still a bit hazy about how User.FineOne() does a call to the Mongo. But I'm understanding the code much better now. Thank you for your input.

Comment: This was a huge help. I've been having many of the same issues as a newbie and the fact that express recently was updated to 4.0 certainly doesn't help the situation. For those that are looking for additional help on figuring out certain aspects of the stack -- more specifically, the parts that pertain to MongoDB -- they have an EXCELLENT (free!) course on their site. Check it out as it's well worth the time: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2014_June/about#

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a few link to understand it better. The key is to write better code, you have to see the better code. 
This [link from AirPair CEO](https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive) brings much-needed clarity, especially the last part as we all use Express 4 now.
Second would be this one [toon.io](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/). This one really opened me up a lot. I am still unclear on many things, will add to it Once I get more clarity.
One thing which people fail to mention in their tutorial is that in the production environment you cannot use Express's traditional data store. Obviously express also needs to maintain a table and  it uses something called Memory Store. To use your own session store see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

Hope it helps someone.